# .net 4.5 async syntax

Tags: .net-4.5, async-await

I wrote the code below,

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return 42;
        });
```

but the read line appeared under the "async" keyword, and the code cannot compiled due to some syntax error, can anybody advise me what to do?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use `Task.Run`, which has more natural syntax for `async` lambdas:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  return 42;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to return a `Task<T>`, like so:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<Task<int>>(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return 42;
});
```

The `async` keyword requires to return `Task`, `Task<T>` or `void`. Read more about it: [async (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx).